# Is there a callback for the Next method call?

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I can display the next slide in a slider with a button like this:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    $('#myslider').flexslider('next');
});
```

my question is: is there a way for me to execute code when the slider is finished sliding?  a call to `.flexslider('next', function() { alert('animation finished'); })` would seem most natural but doesn't seem to be supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `after` option during initialization, provided by the plugin.

```
after: function(){},//Callback: function(slider) - Fires after each slider animation completes
```

**[From the docs](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/warrendholmes/9481310/raw/e7815da6e2cb1420dafd67665283ddc669f11242/Flexslider%20Options)**

**[Here's the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/CPpBD/605/)**

---

**UPDATE**

To get the `currentSlide`  and `currentDirection`, you just need to pass `slider` as `parameter` to your `after function` and you can access its `currentSlide` and `direction` properties and get your logic done. Below is the updated `function`

```
after:function(slider){
      $(".result").append("Current Slide - "+(parseInt(slider.currentSlide)+1)+", Current Direction - "+slider.direction);
      $(".result").append("<br/>");
}
```

**[Here's the Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/CPpBD/606/)**

Comment: yes, that's what I ended up doing but it requires a little extra logic since it's generic.  I then have to check what slide I'm on and what direction was clicked to implement the logic.  it would have been much better if I could just declare the callback right into the call

Comment: @ekkis.. AFAIK, there isn't any option provided by `plugin` and you might need to modify `plugin` for that reason. Well if am not wrong you can determine **what `slide` you are on and what direction was clicked** with above functionality.. :)

Comment: @ekkis.. Updated my answer.. check and let me know.. :)